# Providing symbol of linked shared library to shared library opened with dlopen

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, linker, ld

Consider the following files

```
# Makefile

all: libdyn.so libmain.so app

libdyn.so: libdyn.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -shared -o libdyn.so libdyn.cpp

libso.so: libso.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -shared -o libso.so libso.cpp

libmain.so: libmain.cpp libso.so
    g++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -fPIC -shared -o libmain.so libmain.cpp -ldl -L`pwd` -lso

app: main.cpp   g++ -o app main.cpp -ldl
    g++ -o app main.cpp -ldl
```

```
// libdyn.cpp

#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

extern void foo();

void bar() {
    std::cout << "Calling foo..." << std::endl;
    foo();
}

};
```

```
// libso.cpp

#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello from foo" << std::endl;
}

};
```

```
// libmain.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main_fun() {
    void* handle = dlopen("./libdyn.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    void (*bar_ptr)() = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(handle, "bar"));
    std::cout << "Calling bar..." << std::endl;
    (*bar_ptr)();
    return 0;
}
```

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void* handle = dlopen("./libmain.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*main_fun_ptr)() = reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(dlsym(handle, "_Z8main_funv"));
    std::cout << "Calling main_fun..." << std::endl;
    (*main_fun_ptr)(); 
}
```

Calling `./app` yields

```
Calling main_fun...
Calling bar...
Calling foo...
./app: symbol lookup error: ./libdyn.so: undefined symbol: foo
```

and `ldd libmain.so` yields

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd903f8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe05cdb8000)
    libso.so (0x00007fe05cdb3000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe05cb99000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe05ca4a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe05ca2f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe05c83b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe05cddf000)
```

I don't understand why `libdyn` doesn't have access to `foo`. `libmain` links against `libso`, which provides `foo` and `libdyn` is loaded by `libmain`, so shouldn't `foo` then be found?

I am interested in solving this problem, however, there are a few constraints. As could be suspected, this is kind of a MWE for my real problem. In my application `libmain.so` is called using the Java Native Interface. Furthermore, only `libmain` is user code. `libso` and `libdyn` are external libraries that would be very difficult for me to recompile, but it would be doable. Lastly, there isn't a single `foo` function, but thousands and also global variables that must be shared in the way `foo` should be shared.

Comment: As a start, add option `-g` into every compilation. Also check for error after `dlopen`/`dlsym`: in my test the very first `dlopen` fails with error message `dlopen("./libmain.so"): *** libso.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` This can be fixed with `-Wl,-rpath,${PWD}`

Answer (score 1):

In `main.cpp`, use open `RTLD_GLOBAL` in dlopen.

From the manual:

```
RTLD_GLOBAL
    The  symbols  defined by this shared object will be
    made available for symbol resolution
    of subsequently loaded shared objects.
```

Edit: alternatively, instead of linking `libso.so` as dependency into `libmain.so`, call `dlopen` from `main_fun`:

```
dlopen("libso.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

Or perhaps from a shared-object-initializer:

```
static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void init(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "libmain constructor %s running\n", __func__);
    if (!dlopen("libso.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlopen(\"libso.so\"): *** %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
}
```